# Is there any way to expose mongodb database as rest api

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

Is there any way to expose mongodb database as rest api.

I would like to expose my mongo DB database as a rest API.

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/) might help you out. Your question is a very general question. A google search would probably be more helpful than asking on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the details in [this official page](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#rest-interfaces).

Some of the REST Interfaces.

- RESTHeart
- Mongodb Java REST server

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/abilliondreams/mongodb-generic-rest-api

Generic REST API to perform CRUD operation on a monogodb collection.